# Android BillingFlowParams accept multiple subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

In an attempt to display several subscription options, I don't see where I can pass an array of SkuDetails to Billing flow.  Is that correct?  Does the Billing UI not handle multiple SkuDetails?

```html
Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "Getting SKU Details");
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                             List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "Details Returned an RC of : " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                SkuDetails mySKU = null;
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mySKU = skuDetails; // <-- Tests a single one
                        String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                        String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
                        Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "SKU: " + sku + " and price: " + price);
                    }
                    BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(mySKU) // <-- want to pass multiple but wont take a list
                            .build();
                    BillingResult responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(WebViewActivity.this, flowParams);                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG_BILLING, "NO SKU's found");
                }

            }
```

What am I missing to allow the UI to show multiple Subscription options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing to allow the UI to show multiple Subscription
>   options?

The billing library does not have the means to display a list of purchase options, you have to code and display your own list

> // <-- want to pass multiple but wont take a list .build();

Items can only be purchased one by one, so `BillingFlowParams` and `launchBillingFlow()` only accepts one sku and not a list

Comment: Thanks.   I created a list of subscription options, allow the user to choose one and then call process flow on the selected sku.

Comment: @Lluis Felisart How do developers make applications with Cart type random objects purchasing? 
Do all do it without Android Billing

Comment: Online store applications use their own and different billing system that can include a shopping cart, but if your payment product is to enable functionalities in your app then Google forces you to use their billing system.